# How can i change a line in code using vba

Tags: excel, vba

How can i change a line in the code below using vba?

Code

```
    Sub expdate1()
    If IsEmpty(Worksheets(4).range("A1").Value) = True Then
       range("A1").Value = Date
    End If
    Dim Expiry As Date
    Expiry = DateValue(range("A1") + 365)
    If Date > Expiry Then
        MsgBox "Your Subscription Has Expired", 
    vbExclamation, "ATTENTION"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         Subscribe.Show
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    End Sub
```

Line to change
`Expiry = DateValue(range("A1") + 365)`

Change to
`Expiry = DateValue(range("A1") + 30)`

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want to change that line? One way to do that is to store 365 in a variable in your existing VBA. When a circumstance arises where 365 should be changed to 30, change the value of the variable.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function

Comment: I forgot to mention but i am totally new to vba trying to learn by youtube so no joy with the suggestions so far. I would like to have the code changed programmatically. I can change it manually.

Comment: You might have an XY problem here. There shouldn't be any need to change the VBA code programmatically. You better explain what you really want to achieve (requirement) instead of asking about the solution you came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use the next function:

```
Function ReplaceCodeLine(wb As Workbook, strModule As String, strSearch As String, strReplace As String) As Boolean
 Dim VBProj As Object, VBComp As Object, CodeMod As Object
 Dim startL As Long, endL As Long
 Dim strCLine As String, boolFound As Boolean

    Set VBProj = wb.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(strModule)
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
    startL = 1
    With CodeMod
        endL = .CountOfLines
        boolFound = .Find(Target:=strSearch, StartLine:=startL, StartColumn:=1, _
              EndLine:=endL, EndColumn:=255, wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, _
                                                             patternsearch:=False)

        If boolFound Then
            strCLine = Replace(CodeMod.lines(startL, 1), strSearch, _
                                     strReplace, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
            .ReplaceLine startL, strCLine
            ReplaceCodeLine = True
        Else
            ReplaceCodeLine = False
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

It can be tested using the next `Sub`:

```
Sub TestRepCodeLine()
 dim moduleName as string
 moduleName = "MyModule" ' put here your module name
  Debug.Print ReplaceCodeLine(ThisWorkbook, moduleName, "Expiry = DateValue(range(""A1"") + 365)", "Expiry = DateValue(range(""A1"") + 30)")
End Sub
```

The above code will return `True` in Immediate Window, if the code line has been found and replaced...

It works on the workbook having the code (`ThisWorkbook`). If a different workbook needed, please use that one.

But, besides the way of learning how to replace a code line, are you sure that this is really necessary?

Comment: @Wendi: Do you mean that VBA raises an error saying "Not defined error", without highlighting any code line? Please, try the updated `Sub`. Refresh the page (this one) and copy the updated code.

Comment: My mistake FaneDuru, the code works very well. Just i had missed out on the two code working together. I think  i am just stupid. Thank one more time.

Comment: FaneDuru: Just did as you advised. Again thank you.

Comment: @FaneDuru great answer and good question about practicality of such application. Thanks for sharing your knowledge on how to change module code.